# How to url-encode all characters (special and non-special) in bash

Tags: bash, url, encode

How can I url-encode all characters in bash?

For example:
`abcd0123 => %61%62%63%64%30%31%32%33`

I tried the built-in urlencode function in Linux but it only encodes special characters like (.?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in pure Bash, but other shell utilities can be strung together to achieve this result, for example

```sh
urlencode() {
    printf %s "$1" | od -An -tx1 -v -w${#1} | tr ' ' %
}
urlencode abcd0123 # => %61%62%63%64%30%31%32%33
```